# H2O auto_ml with rolling windows

Tags: r, time-series, tidymodels

I am performing a TS model with recipes in R with tidy model. So, I would to implement an **AutoMl regression with H2O** with rolling-window (initial= 52 weeks, asses= 6 weeks) and I am not sure how to set up the Cross Validation plan in the set_engine.

Thank you for your help

Code:

```
#Date range of flu disease cases
data_tbl<-
data_tbl %>% 
  filter(between(week, as.Date("2011-10-03"), as.Date("2023-04-01")))

#splits
splits <- 
  time_series_split(data_tbl,
                    initial= "52 weeks",
                    assess = "6 weeks",
                    cumulative = T
                                         
                      )
splits %>% 
  tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>% print(n=1000)


splits %>% 
  tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>% 
  plot_time_series_cv_plan(
    .date_var= week, 
    .value= cases,
    .title = "Time Series Cross Validation Plan",
    .facet_ncol = 1,
    .line_alpha = 1,
    .interactive= T) 

#Preprocessing
recipe_spec<-
  recipe(cases ~ ., data = training(splits)) %>%
  step_timeseries_signature(week) %>% 
  step_normalize(week_index.num, starts_with("week_year"))  

recipe_spec %>% prep() %>% juice() %>% glimpse


#start h2o
h2o.init(
  nthreads = -1,
  ip       = 'localhost',
  port     = 54321
)

#setting automl
model_spec <- 
  automl_reg(mode = "regression") %>% 
  set_engine(
    engine                     = 'h2o',
    max_runtime_secs           = 100, 
    max_models                 = 50,
    nfolds                     = NULL,# ?????????????????
    exclude_algos              = c("DeepLearning"),
    verbosity                  = NULL,
    seed                       = 786
  )
```

1. Is possible to perform a rolling-window cross validation plan in h2o auto ml?